# Where does AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained() store the model to disk?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I attempted the following on a Windows device:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-small")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-small")
```

It worked, but when I tried to download a larger version of the model:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-XL")
```

I ran out of disk space: `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`

However, it did not appear to delete what it had downloaded, and I can't seem to locate the model files on the disk. Where does it store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases the loaded models are saved in the transformers cache directory.

On Windows, the default directory is given by `C:\Users\username. cache\huggingface\transformers`.

You can specify the cache directory every time you load a model by setting the parameter cache_dir

For python

```
import os
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = '/path/cache/'
```